# Multi-selector Selector in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Hi is there a way to extend the limit of values that the multi-selector accepts? I found out that it limits to only 10 values.

Thanks

I am trying to extend the limit to upto 50 values if possible.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jYNz.png)

this is my code it works perfectly, but it only limits to 10 values:

```
`    #region LocationID
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Location.locationCD, 
        Where<Location.bAccountID, 
            Equal<Current<MAADSupplierRebates.customerID>>,
        And<Location.status, Equal<LocationStatus.active>>>>),
                typeof(Location.locationCD),
                typeof(Location.descr),
        ValidateValue = false)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = MAADMessages.Project, Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string LocationID { get; set; }
    public abstract class locationID : BqlString.Field<locationID> { }
    #endregion`
```

```
   <px:PXMultiSelector ID="edLocationID" runat="server" DataField="LocationID" AutoRefresh="True" AllowCustomItems="true" CommitChanges="True">
   </px:PXMultiSelector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in 23R2, and I can confirm that PXMultiSelector is not limited to 10 items. I also checked the source code of PXMultiSelector, and there was no sign of any limits.
Please see attached image, I was able to select 16 locations.

[image]

You may have somehow disabled your control from expanding vertically and horizontally, and that is why you can't see more values.

Comment: Hi did you use the ID rather than the CD? If I select more than 10 an error pops up that the string is too long

Comment: Hi, yhe maximum length of your field is 255 character. Try to increase it to 500 or 1000.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! it worked! I overlooked the max length of the field indeed. Now I set it to max. Now my question is I was trying to enable the control to expand vertically and I cant seem to find the control. Which control is it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I don't know why your control doesn't expand vertically, you probably set a fix height of it or one of it's parent column or row or form.